# Impose a restriction when choosing values from a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` which I sorted according to the columns `date` and `adj. R&D Ratio`. The first 50 rows of the `dataframe` looks as follows:

```
         date        stock GICS adj R&D Ratio
1  31.12.2000 DK0060336014 1510     3.2788032
2  31.12.2000 GB0002634946 2010     3.1489301
3  31.12.2000 NL0013267909 1510     1.3716449
4  31.12.2000 FR0014003TT8 4510     1.3603767
5  31.12.2000 GB00B63H8491 2010     1.2785898
6  31.12.2000 FR0013176526 2510     1.2757339
7  31.12.2000 GB0005758098 2010     1.2014918
8  31.12.2000 NL0000235190 2010     1.1203695
9  31.12.2000 CH0012255151 2520     1.0961999
10 31.12.2000 DK0060534915 3520     1.0838993
11 31.12.2000 SE0000108656 4520     1.0742266
12 31.12.2000 NL0000226223 4530     1.0637055
13 31.12.2000 NL0000009538 3510     1.0614985
14 31.12.2000 FR0000120578 3520     1.0545063
15 31.12.2000 GB0009895292 3520     1.0446137
16 31.12.2000 FR0000131906 2510     1.0350811
17 31.12.2000 DE000BASF111 1510     1.0321425
18 31.12.2000 FR0000120321 3030     1.0264104
19 31.12.2000 FR0000121972 2010     0.9888394
20 31.12.2000 BE0003470755 1510     0.9875462
21 31.12.2000 SE0000667925 5010     0.9823553
22 31.12.2000 DK0060738599 3510     0.9703896
23 31.12.2000 FR0000121329 2010     0.9353715
24 31.12.2000 GB0009252882 3520     0.9238076
25 31.12.2000 CH0012032048 3520     0.9166875
26 31.12.2000 FR0010307819 2010     0.8880829
27 31.12.2000 CH0012005267 3520     0.8654555
28 31.12.2000 AT0000746409 5510     0.8544338
29 31.12.2000 DE0006048432 3030     0.8503410
30 31.12.2000 GB00B10RZP78 3030     0.8471261
31 31.12.2000 DE0005190003 2510     0.7854462
32 31.12.2000 DE0007164600 4510     0.7837740
33 31.12.2000 SE0000115446 2010     0.7575963
34 31.12.2000 CH0418792922 1510     0.7306865
35 31.12.2000 DE0005200000 3030     0.7260179
36 31.12.2000 NL0012169213 3520     0.7173231
37 31.12.2000 IT0003828271 3520     0.6893013
38 31.12.2000 IE0004906560 3020     0.6787389
39 31.12.2000 DE0007010803 2010     0.6667161
40 31.12.2000 DK0010272632 3510     0.6535777
41 31.12.2000 FR0000120271 1010     0.6426599
42 31.12.2000 NL0000334118 4530     0.6390019
43 31.12.2000 CH0012100191 3520     0.5960179
44 31.12.2000 GB0009223206 3510     0.5941659
45 31.12.2000 SE0000695876 2010     0.5940705
46 31.12.2000 NL00150001Q9 2510     0.5835512
47 31.12.2000 CH0030170408 2010     0.5802350
48 31.12.2000 FI0009000681 4520     0.5793825
49 31.12.2000 DE0007664039 2510     0.5673987
50 31.12.2000 GB0007188757 1510     0.5402853
```

My aim is to choose the `30 stocks` with the highest `adj R&D Ratio`. Therefore I use the following code:

```
Portfolio <- Adjusted_RD_Ratio  %>% #make long pivots
  arrange(date,desc(`adj R&D Ratio`)) %>%  #sort by dates and score descending
  group_by(date) %>%  #group by dates important for next step
  slice_head(n = 30) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Rank=1:30)
```

Additionally, I now want to impose a restriction that maximum `5 stocks` out of the same `GICS` sector code can be choosen. When the cap for a `GICS` sector is achieved, the next stocks from a `GICS` sector which has still not achieved 5 stocks should be considered according to the descending order of the `adj R&D Ratio`.

Has somebody an idea of how to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

```
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", "31.12.2000", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", 
"31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2001", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", "31.12.2002", 
"31.12.2002", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", 
"31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", 
"31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", 
"31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", 
"31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", 
"31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", 
"31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", 
"31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", 
"31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", 
"31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", 
"31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", "31.12.2003", 
"31.12.2003", "31.12.2003"), stock = c("GB0007980591", "AT0000743059", 
"ES0173516115", "FR0000120271", "NO0010096985", "LU1598757687", 
"BE0974320526", "SE0000112724", "FR0000120073", "CH0012214059", 
"NL0013267909", "BE0003470755", "CH0016440353", "DE0006047004", 
"FI0009000459", "CH0010645932", "GB0007188757", "GB00B1XZS820", 
"DE000BASF111", "AT0000831706", "NL0000009827", "FI0009005961", 
"SE0015811559", "DE000A3E5D64", "DK0060336014", "IE00BZ12WP82", 
"CH0418792922", "AT0000730007", "DE0007010803", "DE0007030009", 
"FR0000121972", "FR0000125007", "SE0000667891", "DK0061539921", 
"NO0003043309", "CH0001752309", "CH0002432174", "CH0006372897", 
"FR0014004L86", "SE0000108227", "FI0009003727", "GB00B63H8491", 
"SE0000114837", "SE0000115446", "CH0012221716", "FR0000073272", 
"IE0004927939", "SE0000695876", "SE0007100581", "SE0011166610", 
"GB0009465807", "CH0024638196", "CH0030170408", "GB0002634946", 
"FR0000120503", "GB00BGLP8L22", "CH1101098163", "IT0001078911", 
"NL0000235190", "FR0010307819", "FR0000121329", "GB0005758098", 
"ES0143416115", "NL0000395903", "NO0005668905", "DE0007664039", 
"DE0005439004", "FR0000121261", "FR0000131906", "NL00150001Q9", 
"DE0005190003", "FR0000121147", "FR0013176526", "FI0009005318", 
"SE0016589188", "FR0000130403", "DE0006969603", "DE000A1EWWW0", 
"DE000A1PHFF7", "CH0012255151", "FR0000121667", "FR0000121014", 
"IE00BWT6H894", "GB0033195214", "BE0974293251", "CH0010570759", 
"CH0038863350", "SE0015812219", "FR0000120644", "DK0010181759", 
"IE0000669501", "GB0002875804", "GB0006731235", "IE0004906560", 
"FR0000120321", "DE0005200000", "DE0006048432", "GB00B10RZP78", 
"SE0000202624", "DK0060738599", "DK0010272632", "DE0007165631", 
"DE0005785604", "DE0005785802", "GB0009223206", "NL0000009538", 
"DK0060534915", "DE000BAY0017", "CH0364749348", "DK0010272202", 
"BE0003739530", "IT0003828271", "DE0006599905", "CH0012100191", 
"CH0014284498", "CH0012005267", "CH0012032048", "CH0012530207", 
"NL0012169213", "CH0013841017", "GB0009252882", "FR0000120578", 
"GB0009895292", "DK0060495240", "DE0006452907", "DE0007164600", 
"CH0012453913", "FR0014003TT8", "GB00B8C3BL03", "SE0015961909", 
"SE0000108656", "GB0003308607", "FI0009000681", "NL0012866412", 
"NO0003055501", "NL0000334118", "NL0000226223", "FI0009007884", 
"ES0178430E18", "IT0003497168", "SE0000667925", "DE0005557508", 
"NO0010063308", "DE000ENAG999", "FI0009007132", "FR0010208488", 
"ES0130670112", "AT0000746409", "GB0007980591", "AT0000743059", 
"ES0173516115", "FR0000120271", "NO0010096985", "LU1598757687", 
"BE0974320526", "SE0000112724", "FR0000120073", "CH0012214059", 
"NL0013267909", "BE0003470755", "CH0016440353", "DE0006047004", 
"FI0009000459", "CH0010645932", "GB0007188757", "GB00B1XZS820", 
"DE000BASF111", "AT0000831706", "NL0000009827", "FI0009005961", 
"SE0015811559", "DE000A3E5D64", "DK0060336014", "IE00BZ12WP82", 
"CH0418792922", "AT0000730007", "DE0007010803", "DE0007030009", 
"FR0000121972", "FR0000125007", "SE0000667891", "DK0061539921", 
"NO0003043309", "CH0001752309", "CH0002432174", "CH0006372897", 
"FR0014004L86", "SE0000108227", "FI0009003727", "GB00B63H8491", 
"SE0000114837", "SE0000115446", "CH0012221716", "FR0000073272", 
"IE0004927939", "SE0000695876", "SE0007100581", "SE0011166610", 
"GB0009465807", "CH0024638196", "CH0030170408", "GB0002634946", 
"FR0000120503", "GB00BGLP8L22", "CH1101098163", "IT0001078911", 
"NL0000235190", "FR0010307819", "FR0000121329", "GB0005758098", 
"ES0143416115", "NL0000395903", "NO0005668905", "DE0007664039", 
"DE0005439004", "FR0000121261", "FR0000131906", "NL00150001Q9", 
"DE0005190003", "FR0000121147", "FR0013176526", "FI0009005318", 
"SE0016589188", "FR0000130403", "DE0006969603", "DE000A1EWWW0", 
"DE000A1PHFF7", "CH0012255151", "FR0000121667", "FR0000121014", 
"IE00BWT6H894", "GB0033195214", "BE0974293251", "CH0010570759", 
"CH0038863350", "SE0015812219", "FR0000120644", "DK0010181759", 
"IE0000669501", "GB0002875804", "GB0006731235", "IE0004906560", 
"FR0000120321", "DE0005200000", "DE0006048432", "GB00B10RZP78", 
"SE0000202624", "DK0060738599", "DK0010272632", "DE0007165631", 
"DE0005785604", "DE0005785802", "GB0009223206", "NL0000009538", 
"DK0060534915", "DE000BAY0017", "CH0364749348", "DK0010272202", 
"BE0003739530", "IT0003828271", "DE0006599905", "CH0012100191", 
"CH0014284498", "CH0012005267", "CH0012032048", "CH0012530207", 
"NL0012169213", "CH0013841017", "GB0009252882", "FR0000120578", 
"GB0009895292", "DK0060495240", "DE0006452907", "DE0007164600", 
"CH0012453913", "FR0014003TT8", "GB00B8C3BL03", "SE0015961909", 
"SE0000108656", "GB0003308607", "FI0009000681", "NL0012866412", 
"NO0003055501", "NL0000334118", "NL0000226223", "FI0009007884", 
"ES0178430E18", "IT0003497168", "SE0000667925", "DE0005557508", 
"NO0010063308", "DE000ENAG999", "FI0009007132", "FR0010208488", 
"ES0130670112", "AT0000746409", "GB0007980591", "AT0000743059", 
"ES0173516115", "FR0000120271", "NO0010096985", "LU1598757687", 
"BE0974320526", "SE0000112724", "FR0000120073", "CH0012214059", 
"NL0013267909", "BE0003470755", "CH0016440353", "DE0006047004", 
"FI0009000459", "CH0010645932", "GB0007188757", "GB00B1XZS820", 
"DE000BASF111", "AT0000831706", "NL0000009827", "FI0009005961", 
"SE0015811559", "DE000A3E5D64", "DK0060336014", "IE00BZ12WP82", 
"CH0418792922", "AT0000730007", "DE0007010803", "DE0007030009", 
"FR0000121972", "FR0000125007", "SE0000667891", "DK0061539921", 
"NO0003043309", "CH0001752309", "CH0002432174", "CH0006372897", 
"FR0014004L86", "SE0000108227", "FI0009003727", "GB00B63H8491", 
"SE0000114837", "SE0000115446", "CH0012221716", "FR0000073272", 
"IE0004927939", "SE0000695876", "SE0007100581", "SE0011166610", 
"GB0009465807", "CH0024638196", "CH0030170408", "GB0002634946", 
"FR0000120503", "GB00BGLP8L22", "CH1101098163", "IT0001078911", 
"NL0000235190", "FR0010307819", "FR0000121329", "GB0005758098", 
"ES0143416115", "NL0000395903", "NO0005668905", "DE0007664039", 
"DE0005439004", "FR0000121261", "FR0000131906", "NL00150001Q9", 
"DE0005190003", "FR0000121147", "FR0013176526", "FI0009005318", 
"SE0016589188", "FR0000130403", "DE0006969603", "DE000A1EWWW0", 
"DE000A1PHFF7", "CH0012255151", "FR0000121667", "FR0000121014", 
"IE00BWT6H894", "GB0033195214", "BE0974293251", "CH0010570759", 
"CH0038863350", "SE0015812219", "FR0000120644", "DK0010181759", 
"IE0000669501", "GB0002875804", "GB0006731235", "IE0004906560", 
"FR0000120321", "DE0005200000", "DE0006048432", "GB00B10RZP78", 
"SE0000202624", "DK0060738599", "DK0010272632", "DE0007165631", 
"DE0005785604", "DE0005785802", "GB0009223206", "NL0000009538", 
"DK0060534915", "DE000BAY0017", "CH0364749348", "DK0010272202", 
"BE0003739530", "IT0003828271", "DE0006599905", "CH0012100191", 
"CH0014284498", "CH0012005267", "CH0012032048", "CH0012530207", 
"NL0012169213", "CH0013841017", "GB0009252882", "FR0000120578", 
"GB0009895292", "DK0060495240", "DE0006452907", "DE0007164600", 
"CH0012453913", "FR0014003TT8", "GB00B8C3BL03", "SE0015961909", 
"SE0000108656", "GB0003308607", "FI0009000681", "NL0012866412", 
"NO0003055501", "NL0000334118", "NL0000226223", "FI0009007884", 
"ES0178430E18", "IT0003497168", "SE0000667925", "DE0005557508", 
"NO0010063308", "DE000ENAG999", "FI0009007132", "FR0010208488", 
"ES0130670112", "AT0000746409", "GB0007980591", "AT0000743059", 
"ES0173516115", "FR0000120271", "NO0010096985", "LU1598757687", 
"BE0974320526", "SE0000112724", "FR0000120073", "CH0012214059", 
"NL0013267909", "BE0003470755", "CH0016440353", "DE0006047004", 
"FI0009000459", "CH0010645932", "GB0007188757", "GB00B1XZS820", 
"DE000BASF111", "AT0000831706", "NL0000009827", "FI0009005961", 
"SE0015811559", "DE000A3E5D64", "DK0060336014", "IE00BZ12WP82", 
"CH0418792922", "AT0000730007", "DE0007010803", "DE0007030009", 
"FR0000121972", "FR0000125007", "SE0000667891", "DK0061539921", 
"NO0003043309", "CH0001752309", "CH0002432174", "CH0006372897", 
"FR0014004L86", "SE0000108227", "FI0009003727", "GB00B63H8491", 
"SE0000114837", "SE0000115446", "CH0012221716", "FR0000073272", 
"IE0004927939", "SE0000695876", "SE0007100581", "SE0011166610", 
"GB0009465807", "CH0024638196", "CH0030170408", "GB0002634946", 
"FR0000120503", "GB00BGLP8L22"), GICS = c(1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 
1010L, 1010L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 
1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 
1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2020L, 2020L, 2510L, 
2510L, 2510L, 2510L, 2510L, 2510L, 2510L, 2510L, 2510L, 2520L, 
2520L, 2520L, 2520L, 2520L, 2520L, 2520L, 2520L, 2530L, 2550L, 
3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 
3020L, 3030L, 3030L, 3030L, 3030L, 3510L, 3510L, 3510L, 3510L, 
3510L, 3510L, 3510L, 3510L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 
3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 
3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 4510L, 4510L, 4510L, 4510L, 4510L, 4510L, 
4520L, 4520L, 4520L, 4520L, 4530L, 4530L, 4530L, 4530L, 5010L, 
5010L, 5010L, 5010L, 5010L, 5010L, 5510L, 5510L, 5510L, 5510L, 
5510L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 
1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 
1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 
1510L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2020L, 2020L, 2510L, 2510L, 2510L, 2510L, 2510L, 2510L, 
2510L, 2510L, 2510L, 2520L, 2520L, 2520L, 2520L, 2520L, 2520L, 
2520L, 2520L, 2530L, 2550L, 3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 
3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 3030L, 3030L, 3030L, 3030L, 
3510L, 3510L, 3510L, 3510L, 3510L, 3510L, 3510L, 3510L, 3520L, 
3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 
3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 4510L, 4510L, 
4510L, 4510L, 4510L, 4510L, 4520L, 4520L, 4520L, 4520L, 4530L, 
4530L, 4530L, 4530L, 5010L, 5010L, 5010L, 5010L, 5010L, 5010L, 
5510L, 5510L, 5510L, 5510L, 5510L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 
1010L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 
1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 
1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2020L, 2020L, 2510L, 2510L, 
2510L, 2510L, 2510L, 2510L, 2510L, 2510L, 2510L, 2520L, 2520L, 
2520L, 2520L, 2520L, 2520L, 2520L, 2520L, 2530L, 2550L, 3020L, 
3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 3020L, 
3030L, 3030L, 3030L, 3030L, 3510L, 3510L, 3510L, 3510L, 3510L, 
3510L, 3510L, 3510L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 
3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 3520L, 
3520L, 3520L, 4510L, 4510L, 4510L, 4510L, 4510L, 4510L, 4520L, 
4520L, 4520L, 4520L, 4530L, 4530L, 4530L, 4530L, 5010L, 5010L, 
5010L, 5010L, 5010L, 5010L, 5510L, 5510L, 5510L, 5510L, 5510L, 
1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 
1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 
1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 1510L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L), `adj R&D Ratio` = c(0.348155241119327, 0.308311789187149, 
0, 0.642659933709443, 0.362284696408923, 0, 0, 0.265064652566881, 
0, 0, 1.3716448579888, 0.987546214844275, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.540285314948445, 
0.246014967343632, 1.03214245194207, 0, 0, 0, 0.38813139306808, 
0.508049430058752, 3.278803238908, 0.313371910811858, 0.730686542892275, 
0, 0.685094617352839, 0, 0.986658578864182, 0.209939934569318, 
0.533731615464964, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.192228213829493, 0, 0, 0, 1.27576996862804, 
0.389884935527518, 0.7559254783163, 0, 0, 0, 0.592760314339032, 
0.326830553905841, 0.419963119618002, 0.157465997671278, 0.308474346065886, 
0.578955367565927, 3.14198530645716, 0, 0.243399720846679, 0, 
0, 1.1178985422591, 0.886124286528083, 0.933308611949108, 1.19884196016655, 
0, 0, 0, 0.567398706320641, 0, 0, 1.03508108032538, 0.583551165057629, 
0.785446163338981, 0, 1.27573387367582, 0, 0, 0.157384430388781, 
0, 0, 0, 1.09619990329866, 0, 0.117288099499881, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.432907995571292, 0, 0.297104334427303, 0, 0, 0.164654206396396, 
0.0616574435115365, 0.678738923154843, 1.02641040895497, 0.726017895208422, 
0.850341015921822, 0.847126067171272, 0.280729520707776, 0.970389589309208, 
0.653577670582228, 0, 0, 0.110446021210623, 0.59416587220934, 
1.06149854528088, 1.08389931674238, 0.539248805707932, 0, 0.263468728853693, 
0, 0.689301285790686, 0.526846235537207, 0.613801350400133, 0.329455351730347, 
0.865455522409555, 0.916687482889656, 0, 0.717323050856873, 0.364810458633517, 
0.923807556377483, 1.05450633395584, 1.04461369626387, 0, 0, 
0.783773997697676, 0.396370333452717, 1.36037667050387, 0.477654303183566, 
0.0360646916525175, 1.07422661223121, 0.377240762523683, 0.579382530689806, 
0.446680920878707, 0, 0.639001944311312, 1.06370553923918, 0, 
0, 0, 0.98235530252385, 0, 0, 0.265600708617901, 0, 0, 0, 0.854433767763663, 
0.201927413394085, 0.274129354537357, 0, 0.47680927287233, 0.302531781574416, 
0, 0, 0.192945746751328, 0, 0, 1.46263534955525, 0.952288658875395, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.505128883590175, 0.215873962148967, 0.934894836924315, 
0, 0, 0, 0.301493654663015, 0.485989797635933, 3.12257194212532, 
0.311775702586192, 0.733451590567599, 0, 0.601685124231466, 0, 
1.08026385220228, 0.218051857386941, 0.55856851034172, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.0701507512256765, 0, 0, 0, 1.17153985695965, 0.546402750649552, 
0.589800473197486, 0, 0, 0, 0.446615805191319, 0.337622266855034, 
0.448266105001595, 0.135948341861317, 0.319018245163337, 0.696740631904583, 
4.00144588515066, 0, 0.300208974607643, 0, 0, 1.23786073127374, 
0.909658681216208, 0.871846217450788, 1.21973410815926, 0, 0, 
1.05263157894737, 0.796341696166487, 0.796245684410749, 0, 1.03662722433986, 
0.591516035043152, 0.841990318475533, 0, 1.17788594574777, 0, 
0, 0.0484716788902265, 0, 0.342823132395847, 0, 0, 0, 0.0737208693391075, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.334281730349548, 0, 0.212168879517065, 0, 0.0343201969475623, 
0.114102616805445, 0.0386057502830502, 0.475998376860053, 0.766062211525202, 
0.493537738022368, 0.639927261544939, 0.557185345643263, 0.325386086922749, 
0.880107755827675, 0.593197579885409, 0.667250813965762, 0.205289682856566, 
0.0895971132362813, 0.573868081473294, 1.2490069686656, 1.10385280671179, 
0.56567580491217, 0, 0.699294346437204, 0, 0.471918248076076, 
0.49579258545322, 0.785964208161947, 0.308875000991175, 0.875169473473618, 
0.882493788984404, 0, 0.670912988984689, 0.269303486595569, 0.82438407477315, 
1.05052713746408, 1.09502168818641, 0.358529337103318, 0, 0.641046573016473, 
0.718440957294033, 1.46926507117661, 0.54180725824382, 0.0565251549655809, 
1.08535607397206, 0.300004199661506, 0.516315580824989, 0.408049566606371, 
0, 0.933727056747273, 1.01169522527989, 0, 0, 0, 0.55508363946608, 
0.453935481796046, 0, 0.339717575869076, 0, 0, 0, 0.0224159466567322, 
0.238326175524057, 0.281633191906362, 0, 0.400903843039083, 0.23633700026716, 
0, 0, 0.155782009690722, 0.253589106251182, 0, 1.42573034675602, 
1.10289757392777, 0.820958198286726, 0, 0.121243485954335, 0, 
0.401853298599386, 0.176328771471093, 0.771205919719764, 0, 0, 
0, 0.228503333899315, 0.485760891836534, 2.81558930126304, 0.294532824977541, 
0, 0, 0.755170639318799, 0, 1.08103823610396, 0.21354647402288, 
0.579503100339761, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0800925897730931, 0, 0, 0, 1.06325037456255, 
0.552399355502998, 0.65312561277287, 0, 0, 0, 0.504288948870772, 
0.349931432625589, 0.392093839174648, 0.136285237477173, 0.337073135197932, 
0.56407493700002, 4.11286855185496, 0.281322434520689, 0.359937879417767, 
0, 0, 1.45249010632265, 0.969763800057246, 0.80251763830963, 
1.17955545828545, 0, 0, 1.05263157894737, 0.927066526472698, 
0.844185952173605, 0, 0.616750924915803, 0.595220672513441, 0.986082016872856, 
0, 1.15403108317551, 0, 0, 0.055910225080283, 0, 0.309451802101752, 
0, 0.831521835559022, 0, 0.0879392874947248, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.323665374288555, 
0, 0.233024445765765, 0, 0.056207036565913, 0.123197095688553, 
0.0313521066253501, 0.49646315780896, 0.779562187915442, 0.465769196872944, 
0.637018245580238, 0.57368119779029, 0.241812505225029, 0.583924104558891, 
1.40499366743767, 0.406252907662551, 0.154742075922361, 0.0785348679592576, 
0.464913731136435, 0.805003049011491, 0.974988442719951, 0.533653277021197, 
0, 1.17811715148882, 0, 0.437309299538281, 0.497656851639223, 
0.678371898006081, 0.288808784309066, 0.835472095971294, 0.886671141826413, 
0, 0.578872913702843, 0.195940508478262, 0.838696519213617, 1.00321976873748, 
1.05527623134355, 0.289120415984064, 0, 0.670163085528901, 0.65339576406265, 
1.54972819078517, 0.572536385751392, 0.0436549782043242, 1.08357444497098, 
0.312680391134772, 0.526411478497764, 0.265403132516072, 0.0651659617812408, 
1.00754954212556, 0.957219261288471, 0, 0, 0, 0.46593716924571, 
0.398113183196323, 0, 0.252856571472995, 0, 0, 0, 0.0252135796317245, 
0.167448066460122, 0.27484449895293, 0, 0.358193899145724, 0.206757300588434, 
0, 0.219763407371917, 0.150443968793461, 0.242185024660507, 0, 
1.47355352272133, 1.15909231861372, 0.736560941449678, 0, 0.143973217975224, 
0, 0.352427474755206, 0.190789261817793, 0.71794103213898, 0, 
0, 0, 0.2132739424551, 0.470744782765732, 2.73994933900873, 0.289702542048908, 
0, 0, 0.755973395699601, 0, 1.06080329618206, 0.19498164397433, 
0.541958621909451, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.144853400240604, 0, 0, 0, 0.938554810908235, 
0.432521947927588, 0.702478826332285, 0, 0, 0, 0.498973877476859, 
0.350000211731058, 0.371015411278701, 0.148823783006403, 0.343394792573242, 
0.556472496679883, 3.85095094444878, 0.0699049459274819, 0.335619027919786
)), row.names = c(NA, 500L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(Adjusted_RD_Ratio)`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Quinten I've uploaded the question.

Answer (score 0):

I will first create a column `GICS_count` indicating the number of times a `GICS` code appears. Then use `filter` to keep those that is less than 6.

The first 10 rows of the output is pasted here for reference.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(GICS) %>% 
  mutate(GICS_count = seq(1, n())) %>% 
  filter(GICS_count < 6) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(date,desc(`adj R&D Ratio`)) %>%
  slice_head(n = 30) %>% 
  group_by(date)

# A tibble: 30 × 5
# Groups:   date [1]
   date       stock         GICS `adj R&D Ratio` GICS_count
   <chr>      <chr>        <int>           <dbl>      <int>
 1 31.12.2000 DK0060336014  1510            3.28          1
 2 31.12.2000 GB0002634946  2010            3.15          1
 3 31.12.2000 NL0013267909  1510            1.37          2
 4 31.12.2000 FR0014003TT8  4510            1.36          1
 5 31.12.2000 GB00B63H8491  2010            1.28          2
 6 31.12.2000 FR0013176526  2510            1.28          1
 7 31.12.2000 GB0005758098  2010            1.20          3
 8 31.12.2000 NL0000235190  2010            1.12          4
 9 31.12.2000 CH0012255151  2520            1.10          1
10 31.12.2000 DK0060534915  3520            1.08          1
```